# Google Analytics: Disable tracking for country/region

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, country-specific

I'm using Google analytics on a small business website from Germany. Today I noticed 86 visitors from Palo Alto on a Sunday. No matter where they come from and why there are visiting the site, they are distorting the statistics. I'm only interested in visitors from Germany.

Is there any way to get rid of this traffic sources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create an Advanced Segment. Towards the top of the page you will notice a button called "Advanced Segments".  Click that and then choose "+New Advanced Segment".

You will need to **exclude** location, then type in Palo Alto. That will now remove any traffic that has come from that area.

Comment: So again, how would a user only include specific countries? Using the suggested method, one would be required to "Exclude" each and every country in the world but for one. (in my case, two...or one continent)

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to make a new view, and filter the country or city location out of that view (keeping a 'master view' that does not have the filter, as a back-up).

Do this in admin for that view with a custom filter excluding the city you don't want to see. OR to only include Germany.